# Как убрать последний символ "," в строке в выводе?

Tags: python, print

У меня есть список `list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '', '4', '5', '6']`. Нужно вывести его так:

```
 a,b,c
 1,2,3
 4,5,6
```

У меня получается так:

```
a,b,c,
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
```

Код

```
cnt = 0
for i in lst:
    if i != '':
        print(i, end=',')
    elif i == '':
        cnt += 1
        if cnt % 2 == 0:
            print('')
```

Вопрос: как в этом выводе убрать последний символ "," в строке? rstrip(",") не меняет ничего

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(3):
    print(','.join(lst[i*5:i*5+3]))
```

Comment: А если пробельные символы идут через разное количество непробельных? Например, list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '1', '2', '', '', '4', '5', '6']

Comment: Тогда нужно в цикле искать следующий пробельный

Answer (score 1):

Через `end=','` не получится, нужно как-то исхитряться. У меня так получилось:

```py
list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '', '4', '5', '6']

first = True
for x in list_:
    if not x:
        if not first:
            print()
            first = True
    else:
        if not first:
            print(', ', end='')
        print(x, end='')
        first = False
```

Вывод:

```
a, b, c
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

это можно реализовать и самому, но есть удобная библиотека [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
from more_itertools import chunked

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '', '4', '5', '6']

for i in chunked(filter(lambda x: x!='', lst), 3):
   print(*i, sep=',')

>>> out
'''
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```